# Can't render the page with ejs routing params and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

Ok, I've got an user object:

```
{
  posts: [
    {
      _id: 603f1c1b966c28291cb61d60,
      title: '1111',
      content: '1111',
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: 603f5479c989d92fbc1d082c,
      title: '222',
      content: '222',
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: 603f5e39ddcda01f281f8931,
      title: '3333',
      content: '3333',
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  _id: 603f1c14966c28291cb61d5f,
  username: '1',
  mail: '1@1.ru',
  __v: 3
}
```

On the main page with all posts i click "read more" on single post,(button has a value of this post's id, i checked, at this point everything OK) and new page with single complete post should render, with two values: title and content, simple.
Here's what i do in app.js:

```
app.get("/posts/:postID", function(req, res) {
  const postID = req.params.postID;

User.findById(req.user.id, (err, user)=>{
user.posts.find(post=>{
  post._id === postID;
  console.log(post);
});
});
```

At this point log return all 3 posts.Why? I've tried different ways, and as i remember, i've got post i needed, but still coudnt render data from it. Post page is:

```
<div class="block">
  <h1><%= title %></h1>
  <p><%= content %></p>
</div>
});
```

And when i tried:

```
res.render("post",{
  title:post.title,
  content: post.content
})
```

that didn't work.But, if i try for example:

```
res.render("post",{
  title:req.user.posts[0].title,
  content: req.user.posts[0].content
})
```

, that works.

Can anyone help me? And remember, User.find - data from mongoDB, req.user - same data, but stored in session when user logged in. I guess it,s not that good to render data from sesion. But, at this point any solution is acceptable, i stacked badly)

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that you can take here:

1. Use an if condition and return only the matching element.

```
app.get("/posts/:postID", function (req, res) {
  const postID = req.params.postID;

  User.findById(req.user.id, (err, user) => {
    user.posts.find(post => {
      if (post._id === postID) {
        console.log(post);
      }
    });
  });
```

2. Return only the desired element directly from the query.
   Excuse me for taking the liberty and modifying the code a bit.

```
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId; // Hoping you are using mongoose.

app.get("/posts/:postID", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const postID = req.params.postID;
    let post = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          "_id": ObjectId(req.user.id)
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$posts"
      },
      {
        $match: {
          "posts._id": ObjectId(postID)
        }
      }
    ]);
    if (post && post.length > 0) {
      console.log(post[0])
      return post; // or anyhow you want to format and return 
    }
  } catch (exception) {
    // Handle how you want.
  }
});
```